# Grails controller action executed multiple times

Tags: grails, groovy, controller, request, action

A strange problem occuring in this snippet:

```
class FooController {

  def barService

  def update = {
    log.debug("I'm getting executed")
    barService.doFoo()
    render "Done"
  }
}
```

When I now enter `http://my.domain.tld/fancyapp/foo/update` in a browser (Firefox in my case), the code in `update` is executed three times.

---

**EDIT 1:** barService.doFoo() contains heavy calculations, so it takes quite long to finish.

---

**EDIT 2:** @hvgotcodes: no, sorry, no authentication and my UrlMappings.groovy looks like this:

```
class UrlMappings {
  static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
      constraints {
        // apply constraints here
      }
    }
    "/"(view:"/index")
    "500"(view:'/error')
  }
}
```

@Jarred: No, only the usual suspects `Bootstrap.groovy`, `BuildConfig.groovy`, `Config.groovy`, `DataSource.groovy` and `UrlMappings.groovy`.

Hints anyone?

Comment: something else is going on -- do you have any url mappings, authentication, or anything else?

Comment: Do you have any Filters in your conf/ directory?

Comment: Quick responses - I updated the question with answers and code.

Comment: how do check it is executed 3 times ?

Comment: I added a log.debug() before the barService.doFoo() call.

Comment: Take out the barService.doFoo() call and see if it still executes 3 times.  I can't imagine what it would be doing, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: It could be that doFoo() is taking so long, firefox keeps requesting. Did you try it with curl?

Comment: @RobertoGuerra: Good point, just tried, but no cigar.

Comment: When you mean it is executed three times? does render "Done" get executed 3x also? If not, it could be something inside doFoo()

Comment: Ok, I followed Jarreds suggestion and the action is only executed once; it looks like the multiple executions result from the time consuming doFoo(). Any suggestions on how to keep the first request alive till doFoo() is done?

Comment: Make doFoo() faster :)  If you don't need a response from doFoo() you could spawn a thread and let it run in the background.  But I would think there is a way to set the timeout of a request (which is probably a better solution for you) I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: @JarredOlson: I did so and it seems to work. It looks like the additional requests were triggered due to some obscure timeout. Thanks to everyone for your quick responses and help! Btw: Does anyone wat to 'answer' the question regarding the origin of the additional requests?

Comment: What was the solution?  Making it faster?  Spawning a thread? Increasing the timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the request takes too long the browser may retry the request.  If you can improve the performance of your doFoo() method it should only execute once.